# Run PHP project on my wifi IP like as localhost - Apache2

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, networking

I'm new to PHP, I'm trying to run my project on my local **IP address** of **WIFI** connection. I'm using **UBUNTU** OS in my local machine.

I can access the project from `localhost` right now. I don't know how do I configure my wifi IP address with **APACHE2** so it can also run like as the `localhost`.

Please help and suggest a way to get the project running mode

Comment: [here, and many others in google ..](https://serverfault.com/questions/209150/how-to-access-localhost-by-ip-address)

Comment: Also [This article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-apache-web-server-on-an-ubuntu-or-debian-vps) and [This article](https://lowendbox.com/blog/how-to-setup-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04/) may help a bit